# add trailing zeroes if a number is an integer in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

i have this script that uses a Regex to format a number and show only 2 digits after the float point:

```
let value =9.0111;
var n = value.toString().match(/^-?\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?/)[0];
console.log(n)
//Output: 9.01
```

how to show two zero digits after the float point *if the let value is an integer*?

like `9.00` ?

is there a way to do it using only the RegEx ?

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regexp? Most languages have a function for formatting numbers with a specified number of digits after the decimal.

Comment: Those aren't leading zeroes, they're trailing zeroes.

Comment: Your regexp is for matching numbers, it doesn't format them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for `toFixed`:

```js
console.log((9.01111).toFixed(2)); // 9.01
console.log((9.01).toFixed(2));    // 9.01
console.log((9).toFixed(2));       // 9.00
```

[toFixed docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

By the way this question does not have much to do with TypeScript. I think some better tags would be javascript/numbers/number-format etc

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it worked using:    Number.parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);